# Insertar datos en sqlite cordova en tablas relacionadas por llaves foraneas

Tags: ionic, sqlite, cordova, ng-cordova

Estoy tratando de insertar información en una base de datos en un dispositivo móvil utilizando un plugin de cordova para hacer uso de las API'S de sqlite, pero no he podido lograrlo. Estoy desarrollando mi aplicacion usando el framework de desarrollo **Ionic**.

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
insertarTablas: function(db) {

            var datosPersona, datosTelefono, insertarPersona, insertarTelefono, largoPer, largoTel, i, j;

            datosPersona = [{
                cedula: 123456,
                nombre: "pepe",
                apellido: "perez"
            }];

            datosTelefono = [{
                numero: 30020025,
                cedula: 123456
            }, {
                numero: 6998877,
                cedula: 123456
            }, {
                numero: 58965475,
                cedula: 123456
            }];

            insertarPersona = "INSERT INTO Persona(cedula, nombre, apellido) VALUES(?,?,?)";
            insertarTelefono = "INSERT INTO Telefono(numero, cedula_tel) VALUES(?,?)";

            largoPer = datosPersona.length;
            largoTel = datosTelefono.length;

            for (i = 0; i < largoPer; i++) {
                $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, insertarPersona, [datosPersona[i].cedula, datosPersona[i].nombre, datosPersona[i].apellido]);
            }

            for (i = 0; i < largoTel; i++) {
                $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, insertarTelefono, [datosTelefono[i].numero, datosTelefono[i].cedula]);
            }

        }
```

En esta imagen diferencie con colores los procesos de insertar y consultar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- El color rojo es el registro que se inserto de la persona, osea el objeto persona.
- El color verde, muestra que, muestra que inserto en tres los tres registro, partiendo siempre desde la posición 0.
- El azul cielo, la cantidad de filas afectadas por la consulta, sabiendo que puse como criterio * que especifica a todos, y pues arrojo 1, que es la cantidad de registros.
- Por ultimo un color morado, que muestra un solo registro en la taba de Teléfono, la cual se supone que guardo 3.

Comment: Cual es el problema? Error?

Comment: @sioesi pues no me sale nada especifico, solo que no se esta guardando la información, mas nada, asumo que es eso, ya que cuando hago una consulta para sabe si hay filas con registros, y al menos, ni siquiera ejecuta la consulta, y no ejecuta tampoco el insert

Comment: Puedes dejar el valor de "db"?

Comment: @sioesi regale un minuto y te muestra capturas de pantalla

Comment: Perdon parece que fue error mio, por que ya pude arreglar, deja reviso, disculpa

Comment: @sioesi puedes revisar ahora la imagen, y de paso también, lo que especifico abajo de la imagen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta  asi :

```
var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "my.db"});

insertarPersona = "INSERT INTO Persona(cedula, nombre, apellido) VALUES(?,?,?)";
insertarTelefono = "INSERT INTO Telefono(numero, cedula_tel) VALUES(?,?)";


for (i = 0; i < largoPer; i++) {
db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql(insertarPersona, [datosPersona[i].cedula, datosPersona[i].nombre, datosPersona[i].apellido], function(tx, res) {
        console.log("id insertada: " + res.insertId);
    }, function(e) {
         console.log("ERROR: " + e.message);
    });
 });
}
```

Y para contar los registros

```
  db.transaction(function(tx) {
      tx.executeSql("select count(*) as cnt from Telefono;", [], function(tx, res) {
            console.log("cantidad de registros : "+  res.rows.item(0).cnt);
      });
  })
```

**EDIT**

```
consultarTelefono: function(db) { 
    var consultaTelefono; 
    consultaTelefono = "select count(*) as cnt from Telefono;";     

    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, consultaTelefono, []).then(function(resultado) { 
      console.log(resultado.rows.item(0).cnt);
    });
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Tal como lo conversamos al parecer el error no era de como se ejecutaban las consultas ni tampoco que consulta era, simplemente que en tu codigo tenias mal anexado el item con el contador de tu for

```
for (j = 0; j < largoTel; j++) {
      $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, insertarTelefono, [datosTelefono[j].numero, datosTelefono[j].cedula]);
```

Comment: ya estoy editando para que puedas observar que sucede, si inserta pero la consulta solo me arroja que hay un solo registro, mientras que el de insertar me dice que si inserto 3.

Comment: Como estas haciendo la consulta para ver cuantos registros hay?

Comment: `consultarTelefono: function(db) {

            var consultaTelefono;
            consultaTelefono = "SELECT * FROM Telefono";

            $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, consultaTelefono, []).then(function(resultado) {
                console.log(resultado.rows.length);
            });
        }`

Comment: Actualice @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales

Comment: dejame probar y ya te digo maestro

Comment: Volvi a actualizar @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales  por favor verifica el cambio

Comment: Puse como la primea vez que pusiste no mostro nada, voy a probar la actualizada, se supone que debe funcionar, pero de igual forma, lo unico que hago es saber si afecto, y no deberia la menos de la forma que lo estaba haciendo mostrar solo una, ya te digo, espera

Comment: No me muestra nada tampoco

Comment: Si cambias en tu codigo, la consulta que te deje yo y el console log puedes probar? Me parece extraño que no muestre nada. Nisiquiera un error

Comment: hice exactamente lo que me dijiste y nada amigo

Comment: Te deje el codigo en Edit, es tu mismo codigo distinta consulta, me comentas

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50577/discussion-between-pedro-miguel-pimienta-morales-and-sioesi).